# How to answer a question which has been answered by the same person who asked

Tags: discussion

I have stumbled across a question answered by the guy who asked the question.

[How to import both default and named from ES6 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723020/how-to-import-both-default-and-named-from-es6-module)

I think I can improve it, but I cannot comment (have no reputation) and could not find the way to answer it. Is it because the lack of "reputation" too ?? Disappointed...

Comment: The question was closed last year. Hence you cannot answer it.

Answer (score 5):

You can answer it just like the other questions, but the question you put here is a closed one because the same question has been answered before.

Because of lack of reputation you can't comment on questions, except on your own questions or answers.

Comment: You can of course answer the original question that isn’t closed. However, hopefully your answer is complete, and answers the question by itself (simply submitting an improvement comment isn’t an answer).